# A script for moving files from subdirs to parent dir

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am looking for a script for moving files from  subdirs to the parent directory

My folder structure looks like this.

- Inside of a folder A I have a lot of folders named 1,2,3,4,5...
- All these folders contain 2 more folders named B and C.
- B and C contain files that I want to move one level up, then delete folders B and C.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me with this script

Comment: If i execute something like this inside folder A `find -mindepth 3 -type f -print -exec mv {} . \;` all files end up inside A not where i want them, inside folder 1 or folder 2 etc...

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
find test/*/* -type d | xargs -n1  sh -c 'echo mv -b ${0}/* "$( dirname ${0})" ";" rm -rvf ${0} '
```

It will just print Output on screen as below :

```
mv -b test/1/B/file1 test/1/B/file2 test/1/B/file3 test/1 ; rm -rvf test/1/B
mv -b test/1/C/file1 test/1/C/file2 test/1/C/file3 test/1 ; rm -rvf test/1/C
mv -b test/2/B/file1 test/2/B/file2 test/2/B/file3 test/2 ; rm -rvf test/2/B
mv -b test/2/C/file1 test/2/C/file2 test/2/C/file3 test/2 ; rm -rvf test/2/C
mv -b test/3/B/file1 test/3/B/file2 test/3/B/file3 test/3 ; rm -rvf test/3/B
mv -b test/3/C/file1 test/3/C/file2 test/3/C/file3 test/3 ; rm -rvf test/3/C
mv -b test/4/B/file1 test/4/B/file2 test/4/B/file3 test/4 ; rm -rvf test/4/B
mv -b test/4/C/file1 test/4/C/file2 test/4/C/file3 test/4 ; rm -rvf test/4/C
mv -b test/5/B/file1 test/5/B/file2 test/5/B/file3 test/5 ; rm -rvf test/5/B
mv -b test/5/C/file1 test/5/C/file2 test/5/C/file3 test/5 ; rm -rvf test/5/C
```

If output looks OK then you can simply append  `| sh` at the end of that command, then it will run command which is shows in output.

Answer (score 1):

The following commands will do the job:

```
cd /path/to/A
find -mindepth 3 -type f -execdir mv {} .. \;
find -mindepth 2 -type d -exec rm -d {} \;
```

See also `man find` for differences between `-exec` and `-execdir` actions.

Comment: Nice Radu. ..  ..

Comment: @RahulPatil And your answer is very elegant

Answer (score 1):

Given your directory structure, you don't need `find` for this -- the shell will suffice:

```
# the trailing slash below restricts results to directories
for dir in /path/to/A/*/; do
    mv "$dir"/[BC]/* $dir && rmdir "$dir"/[BC]
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The second set of `for` loops in the script below should do what you're looking for. They're labeled...

> `# move files from subdirs to the parent directory`

The first set creates the kind of file structure you described and there are some file listings (`ls`) to show what's happening.

Run the script as is from within **an empty directory** to verify it does what you want. Then cut out the second set of for loops and alter to use whatever directory and filename patterns you need.

The only thing unusual in this second set is the enclosure of the inner `for` loop inside parenthesis `( ... )`. This is a convenient "bashism" that runs what's inside it in a subshell and so the `cd` only effects the inner `for` loop. If you don't want to use them, remove them and add a `cd ..` following the inner `for` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "
Current dir= $(pwd)
"

# populate directories
for d1 in 1 2 3
do
  for d2 in B C
  do
    mkdir -p $d1/$d2
    for f in 1 2
    do
      touch $d1/$d2/file$d2$f   # include $d2 in filename so unique when merged
    done
  done
done

echo "
ORIGINAL FILE STRUCTURE...
"
# show dirs & files recursively
ls -lR *

# move files from subdirs to the parent directory
for d1 in 1 2 3
do (                    # run in subshell so 'cd' does not change outer loop dir
  cd $d1                #   cd into dir so mv is simpler
  for d2 in B C
  do
    mv $d2/* .          #     Move files in B and C up to parent dir
    #                   #     NOTE: Files in B with same name as
    #                   #           files in C will be silently overwritten!
    rmdir $d2           #     Remove the now empty B and C dirs (OPTIONAL)
  done
)
done

echo "

FINAL FILE STRUCTURE...
"
# show dirs & files recursively
ls -lR *

echo "
Current dir= $(pwd)
"
```